# github logo in latex

Tags: latex

I am creating my resume and I am using \github{username} to show my github. The thing is that the github image is a square with some padding, and the github circle logo inside. I would rather just have the github circle image without the square and padding (making the logo image a little bit bigger). I basically want exactly the \faGithub. Just wondering how the github logo is placed with \github{username} and how I can modify it.

Comment: this is the template I am using: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm#.W479NS8ZPOQ as you can see the github is a square

Comment: Just open `awesome-cv.cls` from the project menu, and search for github. The definition uses `\faGithubSquare`, so if you don't intend to use this command at all, you can just place `\let\faGithubSquare\faGithub` in your preamble and it should work.